# How to debug python code running in an anaconda environment that runs in a docker?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, anaconda, remote-debugging

I am really struggling to be able to debug python that runs in an anaconda environment that is installed in a docker container (that also runs on the same host). I do not have the Dockerfile of the docker image.

I do have installed a docker remote extension in visual code.
My host runs Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

I can run the docker image from the bash shell in VSCode and activate the correct anaconda environment but then I need to select the python interpreter from that anaconda environment but I cannot select it in VSCode.
Only the python interpreters of the host system are visible for selection.

I may be overlooking something here. Any tips/help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to understand "cannot select it in VSCode"? Could you use the Anaconda environment outside of the "docker" project? For the use of "docker" in VSCode, you can refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview) to view related uses.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a non-Docker environment?

Comment: I can debug python application running in an anaconda environment with VSCODE but if the anaconda environment I cannot debug the python code.

Comment: @gorkys -Do you mean that you cannot debug python code outside of VSCode? Please describe the problem you encountered accurately and in detail so that everyone can help you better.